# Google Calendar API does not refresh refresh_token

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I use the google API for a personal project, so I don't have my app verified with google.

I use exactly [this](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/python#step_2_configure_the_sample) code example myself and a `token.json` file gets generated when logging in. Everything works fine, the access token changes more or less every time I make a request (every 10 min).

After a week, the request fails. Exactly a week after the `"expiry"` field in the token.json file.

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Token has been expired or revoked.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Token has been expired or revoked.'})
```

If I understand everything correctly, google should update `refresh_token` as well, but this did not happen.

I thought this part would handle getting a new refresh token:

```py
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request()) ## HERE ##
    else:
```

Might this be caused by my app not being verified? I did not find any information and hardly none about the behavior of the `refresh_token`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to publish your app to production in order to remove the 7 days limitation.

In <kbd>APIs & Services</kbd> / <kbd>Oauth consent screen</kbd>:

[image]

From [google documentation about refresh token expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2?hl=en#expiration):

> A Google Cloud Platform project with an OAuth consent screen
> configured for an external user type and a publishing status of
> "Testing" is issued a refresh token expiring in 7 days.

Also about [Testing publishing status](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615?hl=en#zippy=%2Ctesting):

> Projects configured with a publishing status of Testing are limited to
> up to 100 test users listed in the OAuth consent screen. A test user
> consumes a project's test user quota once added to the project.
>
> Google will display a warning message before allowing a specified test
> user to authorize scopes requested by your project's OAuth clients.
> The warning message confirms the user has test access to your project
> but should consider the risks associated with granting access to their
> data to an unverified app.
>
> **Authorizations by a test user will expire seven days from the time of
> consent. If your OAuth client requests an offline access type and
> receives a refresh token, that token will also expire.**
>
> A Brand Account may authorize scopes requested by your project's OAuth
> clients if a specified test user manages the Brand Account.
>
> A test user may be unable to authorize scopes requested by your
> project's OAuth clients due to the availability of Google Services for
> the account or configured restrictions. A Google Workspace may control
> which third-party apps access its data or an account enrolled in
> Advanced Protection may block most non-Google apps.